# python regex doesn't match dig output

Tags: python, regex, dns, dig

I'm trying to parse some dig output (yes I know about dnspython but it doesn't satisfy my requirements) and have a problem to find a matching regex for my usecase.
I'm trying to find all lines from the dig output with IN and NS in them, and example output looks like this:

```
stackexchange.com.  300 IN  NS  ns1.serverfault.com.
stackexchange.com.  300 IN  NS  ns2.serverfault.com.
```

i tried:

```
if 'NS' in line:
```

and I found some relevant lines, sadly I have some false positives for NSEC DNS entries, e.g.:

```
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - CK0Q5NFFJS5FUB0F2DNA098SBN0O663V NS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM
```

also shows up in my output. 
I know about the `\s` escape which should match any kind of whitespace and tab, howsoever my regex is failing. I currently have

```
for line in output:
    regex = re.compile(r'IN\sNS\s')
    if regex.match(line):
        print(line)
```

But it isn't working. can you help me come up with a regex that doesn't produce false positives?
Any kind of help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `search`, not `match`.

The [match command only matches from the beginning of the string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match).

Additionally, if the amount of whitespace between `IN` and `NS` is flexible, you can quantify one or more matches with `+`.

Your code will be faster if you move the compilation of the regex out of the loop and only compile once:

```
regex = re.compile(r'IN\s+NS\s')
for line in output:
    if regex.search(line):
        print(line)
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I'll mark this as answered in 10mins as SO doesn't allow me to mark it as answered yet.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write \s*

\s only matches one character of whitespace and you have multiple spaces or perhaps a tab that need matching